# Insert a new line after current position in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea with the some lines inside:

> Buy groceries:
>
> 1. tomato
> 2. Onion
> 3. 3 carrots
> 4. greens

I decided to add a new line after onion how can I do that? I want to click after that and add a new line with ctrl + enter combination.

My current code adds a new line to the very end of the textarea：

```
textaAreaField.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey) {     
      this.value += "\n";
    }
});
```

No jQuery pls

Comment: Use `SHIFT` + `ENTER`, as it works "out of the box". No jQuery. No JavaScript.

Comment: I have event listener with blur() on enter, so shift+enter isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use CTRL+ENTER here's a solution:

```js
var textAreaField = document.getElementById('tb');
textAreaField.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
      var position = this.selectionEnd;
      this.value = this.value.substring(0, position) + '\n' + this.value.substring(position);
      this.selectionEnd = position;
    }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="tb"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a live demo to show that `SHIFT` + `ENTER` works out of the box: no shenanigans.

```html
<label>Use <code>SHIFT</code> + <code>ENTER</code> to insert a line break: <br>
<textarea>
1. A
2. B
3. C
</textarea>
</label>
```

Comment: I have event listener with blur() on enter, so shift+enter isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Don't flop UX. Let your users use the default SHIFT + ENTER
Using ENTER to (i.e.) send a chat post - is a common "feature". Users who want/need to create a newline they already know (in such circumstance) that thay can use SHIFT+ENTER to create a newline.   **That's a good *déjà vu* UX.**

So, instead of creating additional functions,  **just improve the one that blurs the textarea**:

```js
var textaAreaField = document.getElementById("textaAreaField");

textaAreaField.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  // Blur only if ENTER was not used in combo with SHIFT
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
     this.blur();
  }
});
```

```css
textarea{font:14px/1.4 sans-serif; width:100%; padding: 8px; box-sizing: border-box;min-height: 160px;}
```

```html
ENTER = blur textarea<br>
ENTER + SHIFT = create newline

<textarea id="textaAreaField">
tomato
Onion
3 carrots
greens</textarea>
```